# TCL::Proc Name From another Proc

Tags: tcl

I would like to spell out the proc name in tcl for building a stronger tcl program. I went through some questions in stackoverflow which talk about the same and I built the following out of it -

```
proc logInfo { {type DEBUG} {msg "This is a debug statement"} } {

set timeStampLog [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%m/%d/%y::%H:%M:%S"]

puts "${timeStampLog}::'[lindex [info level [info level]] 0]'::$type - $msg"

}


proc test { } {

logInfo Warning "This is a test proc only"

}
```

I expect the proc to display the following when called  -

```
tclsh> test
08/05/15::09:41:48::'test'::Warning - This is a test proc only
tclsh>
```

This is what I see -

```
tclsh> test
08/05/15::09:41:48::'logInfo'::Warning - This is a test proc only
tclsh>
```

Is there a way to point to the current proc name?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Current” is a tricky concept sometimes, since when you are running `logInfo`, it really is the current procedure. You want the caller of the current procedure; instead of `info level [info level]`, use `info level -1` (positive numbers count from the base of the stack, zero and negative count from the deep end of the stack).

This actually simplifies your code a bit.

```
proc logInfo { {type DEBUG} {msg "This is a debug statement"} } {
    set timeStampLog [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%m/%d/%y::%H:%M:%S"]
    puts "${timeStampLog}::'[lindex [info level -1] 0]'::$type - $msg"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Donal for the detail explanation as always. Appreciate your help in supporting the tcl community.

I have updated my procedure in the same fashion. Helps me debug and understand the issues in more details.